# Pick data from array of objects and return new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

So, I have:

```
"people": [
                {
                    "first": "Linda",
                    "last": "Donson",
                    "salary": "4000USD"
                },
                {
                    "first": "Mark",
                    "last": "Sullivan",
                    "salary": "3500USD"
                },
        ];
```

Now, I want to convert this into a new array of objects, containing only desired set of data. 
For example:

```
"people": [
                    {
                        "first": "Linda",
                        "salary": "4000USD"
                    },
                    {
                        "first": "Mark",
                        "salary": "3500USD"
                    },
            ];
```

How can I do this? So, it should take out the `"last"` key and its values and return only `"first"` and `"last"`.

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Deleting properties in objects is not hard to research and so is looping over arrays of objects and copying objects.  Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is for others to help you fix **your code**. Even if you only got part of it sorted out and the rest isn't working as expected that would show some effort which is expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is a simple one liner via `map` and `delete` or `map` and ES6 `destructuring` as shown in the 2 examples bellow:

```js
var data = [{
    "first": "Linda",
    "last": "Donson",
    "salary": "4000USD"
  },
  {
    "first": "Mark",
    "last": "Sullivan",
    "salary": "3500USD"
  }
]

console.log(data.map(x => delete(x.salary) && x))
```

Also if you are concerned about mutating the object you can simply use ES6 `destructuring` and the `short object literal notation` to get this:

```
Object.values(data).map(({first, last})  => ({first, last}))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use map function to get a new array with your desired options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```js
var source = [ { first: 'first1', last: 'last1', property1: 'p1-1' }, { first: 'first2', last: 'last2', property1: 'p1-2' }];

var mapped = source.map( function (e) {
  return { first: e.first, property1: e.property1 }
})

console.log('mapped : ', mapped)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would that look in ES6?

Comment: is the same for es6, map is a array prototype method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

you can use arrow function !

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach

```
var peoples = [{
        "first": "Linda",
        "last": "Donson",
        "salary": "4000USD"
    },
    {
        "first": "Mark",
        "last": "Sullivan",
        "salary": "3500USD"
    },
];


// empty array 
var newPeoples = [];


peoples.forEach((people) => {

    // only push desired object inside empty array
    newPeoples.push({
        "first": people.first,
        "salary": people.salary
    });

});


// desired array of objects
console.log(newPeoples);
```